# React.js fire event on navigate away from page or page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I would like to fire off an event to the backend when the app navigates to another page or refresh page. This is my exact use case: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.4.0/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md#withrouter-hoc-higher-order-component. However the function `props.route.setRouteLeaveHook` is no longer available in `react-router-dome 4.3.1`, so it's unclear what to do.

Note I *do not* want to use `componentDidUpdate` because I am making an editing app, so there could be 100s of updates per user session, and calling the backend 100s of times would be too expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  // do something
};
```

Comment: where do I place this function? placing it in `  componentDidMount() { ...}` does not fire on refresh?